# MongoDB Access Error

Tags: mongodb

Getting error something of this sort when accessing MongoDB. Any clue?

```
QueryFailure flag was unauthorized db:monza lock type:-1 client:10.173.78.216 (response was { "$err" : "unauthorized db:monza lock type:-1 client:10.173.78.216", "code" : 10057 }).
```

Comment: What vesion of MongoDB are you running? Hpw are you starting the MongoDB? Are you running with auth enabled?